# PHP $_POST variable does not process input fields generated by Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

I have two files, (file1 and file2). file1 includes file2 in a PHP include statement. File1 also contains a form and prints out all $_POST variables. File2 uses a Javascript button to dynamically change the value in an input field. The problem is that $_POST is empty after submit is pressed. Why is that and how do I fix it?

File1:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<?php include 'file2.php'; ?> 
<input type="submit" /></form>

<?php foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) { echo $key . " belongs to " . $val; } ?>
```

File2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var button = {
        counter : 0,

            count : function() {
            text = document.getElementById("text");
            this.counter++;
            text.setAttribute("value", this.counter);
        }
    };
    </script>

<button type="button" onclick="button.count()">CLICK ME!</button>
<input id="text" type="text" value="0" />
```

Comment: your input requires a name attribute to identify input when it's processed by PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to set `name` attribute:

```
<input id="text" name="text" type="text" value="0" />
```

Comment: I feel very stupid for omitting this. I just tested it (my actual code) and adding name parameter solves the issue. Thanks so much.

Comment: Enjoy ! If you find any of the answer helpful, remember to accept it with a tick in the left side (I write about it because you have no answers accepted already).

Answer (score 2):

```
text.setAttribute("value", this.counter);
```

This is better off as:

```
text.value = this.counter;
```

Also you need a name attribute on your element:

```
<input id="text" name="text" type="text" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt set the name attribute for the field "text".

Corrected code:

```
<input id="text" name="text" type="text" value="0" >
```